# On AWS EKS, how can I update an addon multiple minor versions at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, upgrade, amazon-eks

Some enabled add-on lags far behind the latest version. The add-on is NOT self-managed (checked using the doc with aws eks describe-addon)

That specific addon has no compatibility issues between the current and latest versions for the cluster.

[Am I forced to manually click on each minor version and wait?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APK4q.png)